# how to determine view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have three view controllers A, B and C. Both A and B present view controller C. How can I get to know which view controller presented view controller C?

P.S: I want to hide/unhide some buttons once I determine which view controller presented controller C.

Comment: Your question's not clear. Please explain clearly

Comment: Suppose view controller C is already presented. How will you determine whether view controller A or B presented C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `int` property in `C` viewController as `fromViewController`. when you present view controller from `A` means set to `1`. If `B` means, set to `2`. After presented, when your `C` view controller get call `viewWillAppear`, in this method, based on `fromViewController`, you can hide or show that particular button. [This is simple hack :)]

Code in `C`'s viewWillAppear..

```
if ( self.fromViewController == 1) // Set from viewController while you create C in A Controller
{
 [_hButton setHidden:YES];

}

else if ( self.fromViewController == 2) 
{
  [_hButton setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to go this route, you could just use the tag property of the view controller's view.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Before your view get presented , is it any chance to your view get created?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it many ways, You can declare a Boolean/anyType variable in C view controller.  If you are using segues to present C viewcontroller, you can set desired value for that variable and use that variable while loading C view controller.

Example if you are using segues.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AtoC"]) {
            C *cobj = [segue destinationViewController];
            cobj.variable =TRUE;
    }else
   {
      cobj.variable=FALSE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are presenting a modal view controller, you'll probably be more interested in the **visibleViewController** property, which will give you the controller for the current view whether its presented modally or pushed onto the navigation stack.

Save the **visibleViewController.nibName** before presenting C, in a variable and check to see if visibleViewController.nibName is equal to A or B after C is presented :)

```
//before presenting VC C
appdelegate.myController = self.navigationcontroller.visibleViewController.nibName;

//after VC C is presented
if([appdelegate.myController isEqualToString:@"A"]) {

    //Write your code
}
else {
    //Write other code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**C should not care about A or B.** Instead, have A and B set some state in C that tells it whether or not to show the buttons, or have them set themselves as C's delegate so that C can ask them whether to show the buttons. Either way, you'll be able to use C from other view controllers without having to change C.